# How to handle a destruction of view when replacing fragment using FragmentManager?

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentmanager

Suppose, I have `SomeActivity`. It immediately shows `FragmentA` using following code:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragmentView, FragmentA(), "fragment-a-tag")
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()
```

Of course, after that `FragmentA` is created. It makes some network request and displays a data. Suppose, something happens in `FragmentA` (for instance, button click) and it notifies about that `SomeActivity`. `SomeActivity` in its turn, should display `FragmentB` instead of FragmentA. Here is how I do it:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentView, FragmentB(), "fragment-b-tag")
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
```

`FragmentB` has back button on its toolbar. When it is clicked, `FragmentA` should be displayed again. Of course, `FragmentB` notifies `SomeActivity` about back button press and `SomeActivity` shows `FragmentA` using following way:

```
supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("product")
                ?.let {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragmentView, it, "fragment-a-tag")
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit()
                }
```

It searches `FragmentA` from back stack by its tag and if it exists, it just shows it. But the problem is that `FragmentA`'s view is destroyed. It means, a whole lifecycle of the Fragment is executed again. As I already mentioned, at some point of the lifecycle, there is a network request in `FragmentA`. It means it gets executed again, which is the thing that I want to avoid. Even if the view of the `FragmentA` gets destroyed because of `replace` function, its instance exists in a back stack. It means its data(some variables) also exists and alive. So, the question is how to avoid that heavy operation (like network request) in `FragmentA` when it is displayed again? I tried using `popBackStack` when `FragmentA` should be displayed again, but its result is the same. Android's design seems inconvenient in such a cases. How do you handle problems like that?  Please, don't recommend using `hide/show` methods.

Answer (score 0):

As your fragment interaction starts from fragment A to fragment B through Activity. It needs to be  your first fragment exists in backstack. Whenever your onviewcreated calls try to restrict your fragment to recreate or inflate the xml of your fragment. For that you have to manually check if your view is already there and if it is, dont inflate it in onCreateView.

````
private var isReload: Boolean= false
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

  if(initView!=null)
        {
            isReload=true
        }
        else {
            introbinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_intro_one, container, false)
            initView = introbinding.getRoot()
        }
        return initView
}


Do in onViewCreated

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        if(!isReload) {
            initViews()   // get View ids
            initMembers() // get values or network calls
            setListeners() 
        }
    }```
````